# Cities and States (a few data): single table or splitted?

Tags: mysql, select, foreign-key, primary-key

I am designing a DB schema and I need to store **cities** and **states**. I expect only a **few rows**, let's say, 20 cities. Example:

```
id  | city           | state
1   | Rio de Janeiro | RJ
2   | Niteroi        | RJ
3   | Cabo Frio      | RJ
4   | Nova Friburgo  | RJ
5   | Campos         | RJ
6   | São Paulo      | SP
7   | Santos         | SP
8   | Santo André    | SP
```

As I said, less than **20 cities** and only **2 or 3 states** ( CHAR(2) ). Regarding performance, which is the best: A single table like the above example, or 2 tables with relationship between both?

PS: I'm not expecting any SELECT ... WHERE 'state'... I'll only select by city and then display which state it belongs to.

Thanks

Comment: It depends entirely on what you do with them.  But in any event, you should not be doing DB design worrying about performance at this step.  You design the DB first, according to the data relations.  Do this right and the performance will take care of itself 90% of the time.  Only later when you know if you have a performance problem, should you start worrying about it.

Comment: When the table contains very few rows and does not change frequently you can denormalize it and use single table instead of two. You can add a new data field geo_level to choose between the state level or city level, if you need it in future.

Answer (score 2):

`CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET latin1` takes only 2 bytes.  You are not going to improve significantly on that by using an `id TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte) to 'normalize' it.

Splitting into 2 tables is something I call "over-normalizing".

`JOINs` are pretty cheap, but they are not free.  This is a disadvantage of the 2-table approach.

While you are asking this question, I suggest you implement it both ways, see how big the tables are, see how fast the queries are, etc.  Use it as a learning exercise.

Yes, there *will* be *other* cases where 2 tables is better.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you in all aspects. 2 tables will demand more work to the programmer and brings no practical improvement for the DB.  Over-normalizing was perfect (lol) ! I have pretty much the same information but in the oposite situation in another software: lots of select statements by 'state' column to find state's full name, some other information and cities belonging to it... so in this case 2 table is better. Then I'll also take your suggestion and implement both ways as a learning exercise. Thanks!!

Comment: :)  Even in the case of a separate table for States, I would argue for the key to be `RJ`, `SP`, etc, not `1`, `2`, etc.

Comment: Good point! I'll check it out.